# SugarCRM 6.5 CE: how to customize label in editview using Smarty

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

I'm trying to customize a label in an edit view using `Smarty`.

A field named `decription` should have label `LBL_LABEL_ONE` with a currency symbol if `some_fieds` has value 1, `LBL_LABEL_TWO` otherwise.

With the following code in `detailviewdefs.php`, I have no problems to accomplish this in the view detail:

```
array (
    'name' => 'description',
    'label' => '
        {if $bean->some_field==1}
          {$MOD.LBL_LABEL_ONE} {$CURRENCY}
        {else}
          {$MOD.LBL_LABEL_TWO}
        {/if}',
),
```

Note that `some_field` is a field of the current module and `$CURRENCY` is assigned in `view.detail.php` with the following code:

```
function preDisplay() {
    parent::preDisplay();

    $currency = new Currency();
    $this->ss->assign('CURRENCY', $currency->getDefaultCurrencySymbol());
}
```

Using same code in `editviewdefs.php` I have several problems:

**First:** the following fatal error getting the field of the bean:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in
>   cache/modules/omn_fornitura_gas/EditView.tpl line 506]: syntax error:
>   invalid attribute name: '$bean->some_field'
>   (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 1536) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sugar\include\Smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1095

**Second:** the variable $CURRENCY seems not to be correct:

> {€' module='omn_fornitura_gas'}

instead of

> €

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a puzzle this one.

The reason you're seeing such a thing is that Sugar seems to render Smarty Detail and Edit view definitions quite differently.

**The Problem**

In detail, it very neatly compiles the field as such:

*cache/modules/omn_fornitura_gas/EditView.tpl*

```
{capture name="label" assign="label"}
{if $bean->some_field==1}
{$MOD.LBL_LABEL_ONE} {$CURRENCY}
{else}
{$MOD.LBL_LABEL_TWO}
{/if}{/capture}
```

However, in edit, it tries to insert it as an attribute of a translated label:

*cache/modules/omn_fornitura_gas/EditView.tpl*

```
{capture name="label" assign="label"}{sugar_translate label='
{if $bean->some_field==1}
{$MOD.LBL_LABEL_ONE} {$CURRENCY}
{else}
{$MOD.LBL_LABEL_TWO}
{/if}' module='omn_fornitura_gas'}{/capture}
```

This explains both the issues you're seeing, as it complains about the attribute, and displays the module name in the bottom line.

**So what can we do about it?**

Unfortunately, as the edit/detail templates are compiled and cached by Sugar, we can't feasibly get to them directly without digging quite deeply into the Sugar code.

However, what we can do is work around it by specifying a different label, and then setting that label dynamically, just like you were doing in the metadata, but this time via PHP in view.edit.php.

Try this:

*editviewdefs.php*

```
array (
    'name' => 'description',
    'label' => 'LBL_CUSTOM_LABEL',
),
```

*view.edit.php*

```
function preDisplay() {
    parent::preDisplay();

    $currency = new Currency();
    global $mod_strings;
    if ($this->bean->some_field == "1"){
        $mod_strings['LBL_CUSTOM_LABEL'] = $mod_strings['LBL_LABEL_ONE'] . " " . $currency->getDefaultCurrencySymbol();
    }
    else {
        $mod_strings['LBL_CUSTOM_LABEL'] = $mod_strings['LBL_LABEL_TWO'];
    }
}
```

**What happened there?**

$mod_strings is a global variable in sugar that holds the current module's labels. What we've done here is use that to our advantage, and conditionally set what the label should be by setting the property of this custom label when the view is generated. Appreciated that this isn't technically a solution using Smarty, but I hope my above details can help shine a light on the inability to solve this problem exactly the same as the detail view definitions within Sugar.

Let me know if that helps, or if I can provide any further information!

Comment: Though this is not managed with Smarty, you explained why I can't use smarty. Your solution is quite acceptable.